# How to store the results of a query in a list and use it a a later time in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a list of retailers which sell the product "item1" in the Neo4j database and map it with users who are willing to go to those retailers present in that list. I know I can use relationship-relationship but I want to try it by storing the results in a list and use it later in the query. The database is designed like this:

There are retailers, products and users. I want to create a list of retailers which sells the product "item1" to map it with users who prefer to buy it.

Here is my sample code:

```
    CREATE LIST "item1RetailerList"
    AS
    (MATCH (r:Retailers)
    WHERE r.productName = "item1")

    CREATE (u:Users)-[b:BuysFrom]->(item1RetailerList)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to create user or match users that want to buy from retailers? Can you explain more?

Comment: You want to create a relationship between a user and EACH retailer in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list you want to create is to only be used later within the same query, then this should be fairly easy. We can either use [collect()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) to gather the results into a list and keep them in scope until they're needed, or use [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) to directly get the results of a match into a list. Since pattern comprehension requires a path pattern (a single node pattern with no relationships isn't a path pattern) we can't use pattern comprehension here, we'll need to collect the results with the collect() aggregation function:

```
MATCH (r:Retailers)
WHERE r.productName = "item1"
WITH collect(r) as retailers
...
// match on the users `u` that are interested in buying from the retailers
...
FOREACH (r in retailers | 
 CREATE (u)-[:BuysFrom]->(r) )
```

Comment: Can you help me with this query? 

MATCH (d:Distributor)-[de:DELIVERS]->(r:Retailer)-[s:SELLS]->(p:Product)
WHERE p.name = "b"
and d.rating>4
RETURN DISTINCT(d.name) as newDistList

MATCH (r:Retailer)-[s:SELLS]->(p:Product) WHERE p.name = "b"
FOR EACH (d in DistList|CREATE (r)-[o:Order]->(newDistList)

Comment: Seems unrelated, can you either create a new question for it, or join the neo4j users-slack and ask there?